# Knockout observable field in array to indicate order of items

Tags: html, knockout.js

I have a html view that's connected to Knockout viewmodel, and displays a list of items.
Each item in the list contains a textual name field, and a numeric order field.
A user can perform a "drag and drop" action to items in the UL list.
The "drag and drop" event changes the order of the items as follows:

```
 <div id="wrapper">
<ul data-bind="foreach:Items">
    <li draggable="true"
        ondragover="event.preventDefault();"
        data-bind="event:{dragstart:$root.dragItem,drop:$root.dropItem}">
        <label data-bind="text:name"></label>
        <label data-bind="text:orderNo"></label>
        <input type="text" data-bind="value:name" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var list = [{ name: 'Red', orderNo: 0 }
    , { name: 'Green', orderNo: 1 }
    , { name: 'Blue', orderNo: 2 }];
function viewmodel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Items = ko.mapping.fromJS(list);

    self.ItemToDrag = ko.observable();
    self.dragItem = function (item, event) {
        self.ItemToDrag(item);
        return true;
    }
    self.dropItem = function (item, event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var up = self.ItemToDrag().orderNo() > item.orderNo();
        self.ItemToDrag().orderNo(up ? item.orderNo() - 0.5 : item.orderNo() + 0.5);
        //order this list
        self.Items.sort(function (left, right) {
            return left.orderNo() == right.orderNo() ? 0 : (left.orderNo() < right.orderNo() ? -1 : 1);
        });
        //set integer number
        for (var i = 0; i < self.Items().length; i++) {
            self.Items()[i].orderNo(i);
        }
    }
}


var vm;
$(document).ready(function () {
    vm = new viewmodel();
    ko.applyBindings(vm, $("#wrapper")[0]);
});
```

My question is, if it is possible with Knockout to change the contents of the order field automatically when the items of the list change their order through the UI.
Something like

```
<ul data-bind="foreach:Items,orderKey:orderNo"></ul>
```

Where orderKey indicates the order of the items, and which field to update in case of order change.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you need. This is custom binding, that sorts an array from `foreach` binding before:

```js
  ko.bindingHandlers.foreach["after"] = ["orderKey"];
  ko.bindingHandlers.orderKey = {
     update: function (el, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
         var key = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
         var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
         if("foreach" in allBindings) {
             var array = ko.unwrap(allBindings.foreach);
             array.sort(function(a, b) { return a[key] > b[key]; });
             allBindings.foreach = array;
         }                    
     }
 };
  
  // The model
  var model = { Items: ko.observableArray([{text: 3}, {text: 1}, {text: 2}]) };
  // Apply
  ko.applyBindings(model);

  // This simulate changes in observableArray
  setTimeout(function() { model.Items.push({text: 0}) }, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: Items, orderKey: 'text'">
  <li data-bind="text: text"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no specific binding for that use case. In knockout, however, it is simple to write a custom binding. See [the documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html). In the company I'm working for, we're using a knockout-based framework (developed by us) with tons of custom bindings, some of them really complex.

I just started to create such a binding for your use case. But I realized, it won't fit the purpose unless you have dozens of such lists.

What you can do, however, is to sort put the actual sorting into a [knockout computed](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) and just do the updating of the sort index in your drop function. See example below and don't hesitate to ask if something is not clear.

```js
var list = [{ name: 'Red', orderNo: 0 }
    , { name: 'Green', orderNo: 1 }
    , { name: 'Blue', orderNo: 2 }];
    
function viewmodel() {
    var self = this;
    self._items = ko.mapping.fromJS(list);
    self.Items = ko.pureComputed(function () {
     return self._items().sort(function (a, b) {
       return a.orderNo() < b.orderNo() ? -1 : 1;
      });
    });

    self.ItemToDrag = ko.observable();
    self.dragItem = function (item, event) {
        self.ItemToDrag(item);
        return true;
    }
    self.dropItem = function (item, event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var up = self.ItemToDrag().orderNo() > item.orderNo();
        self.ItemToDrag().orderNo(up ? item.orderNo() - 0.5 : item.orderNo() + 0.5);
    }
}


var vm;
$(document).ready(function () {
    vm = new viewmodel();
    ko.applyBindings(vm, $("#wrapper")[0]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
<ul data-bind="foreach:Items">
    <li draggable="true"
        ondragover="event.preventDefault();"
        data-bind="event:{dragstart:$root.dragItem,drop:$root.dropItem}">
        <label data-bind="text:name"></label>
        <label data-bind="text:orderNo"></label>
        <input type="text" data-bind="value:name" />
    </li>
</ul>
```